# MS-Visio Zoom in/out - how to change default percentage change for the page zoom

Tags: visio

Is it possible to change the default percentage for which the page will be zoomed in/out for each press of the correspondent keyboard shortcut (alt+F6 for Zoom In and Alt+Shift+F6 for Zoom Out)?
By default, the page zoom is changed by ~30% on each shortcut press. Could it be changed to 20%?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say if you can change the zoom increments, but I strongly urge you to learn how to zoom and pan as a "two-handed user".

I use these shortcuts to effortless zoom and pan Visio drawings without thinking about it--ie: I don't lose my train of thought by having to remember how to zoom or pan.

- Zoom in: Ctrl + Shift + Left-click
- Zoom out: Ctrl + Shift + Right-click
- Zoom to region: Ctrl + Shift + Left-drag
- Pan: Ctrl + Shift + Right-drag

You can also zoom and pan using the mouse wheel:

- Pan up, own: mouse wheel
- Pan left, right: Shift + mouse wheel
- Zoom in, out: Ctrl + mouse wheel

To "view fit" the page to the window, press Ctrl + Shift + W.

Funny side note: I've never ever used the Alt + F6 zoom control, and didn't know they existed!