# MS-Visio: shortcut for "Last Zoom"

Tags: visio

In MS-Visio there was a button 'Last Zoom'. In the MS-Visio 2016, I don't see such a button... Does it exist? Is there a keyboard shortcut, which works as 'go-to Last Zoom View'?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ribbon **File** -> **Options** -> **Quick Access Toolbar**

Select **All Commands**, scroll down to **Last Zoom**

and click the **Add** button to add it.

(or you can do a similar operation to add it to the ribbon)

The answer to adding a keyboard shortcut ..

https://superuser.com/questions/698650/how-can-i-set-my-own-custom-keys-for-shortcuts-in-visio-2013

Comment: Great! Works! But how could I now create a shortcut for this command?

Comment: Surely if it's on the Quick Access toolbar that is a shortcut!

Comment: No, I meant a keyboard shortcut (hotkey). Is it possible to assign/create/use someone for the Last Zoom?

Comment: @Chachikoff - added link.

Answer (score 0):

I added the command to my Quick Access Toolbar--thanks for the tip, I've never seen this command before, or I've forgotten about it. Anyway, hovering over the button reveals NO keyboard shortcut.

However, if you press the Alt key, further accessor keys will show up (at least in my Visio Plan 2/O365 installation). So for me, if I press the Alt key, then "0D" shows up over "Last Zoom". This will be different for each user, as Microsoft is simply numbering the quick access functions from left to right.

I removed one of the QAT functions, and my Last Zoom then became Alt + 0D.

I will also copy my answer from another thread, for users that land here, as I think these Visio page navigation shortcuts make it really easy to work with large drawings.

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62704503/ms-visio-zoom-in-out-how-to-change-default-percentage-change-for-the-page-zoom/62775517#62775517):

I use these shortcuts to effortless zoom and pan Visio drawings without thinking about it--ie: I don't lose my train of thought by having to remember how to zoom or pan.

- Zoom in: Ctrl + Shift + Left-click
- Zoom out: Ctrl + Shift + Right-click
- Zoom to region: Ctrl + Shift + Left-drag
- Pan: Ctrl + Shift + Right-drag

You can also zoom and pan using the mouse wheel:

- Pan up, own: mouse wheel
- Pan left, right: Shift + mouse wheel
- Zoom in, out: Ctrl + mouse wheel

To "view fit" the page to the window, press Ctrl + Shift + W.